# Spherical Bessel function closure relations for functions $y_{L}(x)$

Tags: integration, orthogonality, dirac-delta, bessel-functions

The spherical Bessel function closure relation is given by
$$
\frac{2 r^2}{\pi} \int_0^\infty dk \; k^2 j_{L}(r k)j_L(r' k) = \delta(r - r') \ ,
$$
as given in Formula (4.1) in Mehrem, Londergan and Macfarlane's paper [Analytic expressions for integrals of products of spherical Bessel functions](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/24/7/018). Do similar relations exist for the spherical Bessel functions $y_{L}(x)$? That is, formulas of the type
$$
\int_0^\infty dk \; k^2 y_{L}(r k) y_L(r' k) = \ldots \ ,
$$
or cross-products like
$$
\int_0^\infty dk \; k^2 j_{L}(r k) y_L(r' k) = \ldots \ ?
$$

**EDIT**: I also found the above closure relation [(1.17.14) on DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/1.17#E14). Because of the identity $y_L(z) = (-1)^{L+1} j_{-L-1}(z)$ we have $j_{L}(z) = (-1)^{-L} y_{-L-1}(z)$ and it seems that we can rewrite the closure relation as
$$
\frac{2 r^2}{\pi} \int_0^\infty dk \; k^2 (-1)^{-L} y_{-L-1}(r k) (-1)^{-L} y_{-L-1}(r' k) = \delta(r - r') \ ,
$$
and taking $-L -1 \to L$ the above is
$$
\frac{2 r^2}{\pi} \int_0^\infty dk \; k^2 y_{L}(r k) y_{L}(r' k) = \delta(r - r') \ ,
$$
which I think makes sense as long as $L$ is allowed to be negative in the original closure relation I wrote above (which I think is true). Does this make sense? What about a closure relation for $y_{L}j_{L}$ combinations?